# Rename a file (extension) on Mac without changing the created date?

Tags: mac-osx, filesystems

I have several .JPG files and I want them to be .jpg files but every suggested rename script uses "mv" and the manual page (on Mountain Lion) for mv says it does a copy and delete which explains why when I run the script the "created/modified/etc" dates are all changed to the current date. I don't want that to happen. What can I do?

Comment: cp -p source.JPG destination.jpg ; rm source.JPG

Comment: @FrandsHansen No. That doesn't work. I get an error saying the two files are identical.

Comment: make a new dir for them then..

Comment: @FrandsHansen That changes the date. The point here is that I don't want the dates changed. Been so long I'm starting to think it's impossible.

Comment: Yes it can :) I have added an answer to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

So, I want to mess around with these. I even found a good old file, modified in 2006.

```
$ stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" *
1347657595  Sep 14 23:19:55 2012 1.JPG
1347715529  Sep 15 15:25:29 2012 2.JPG
1156277764  Aug 22 22:16:04 2006 3.JPG
1347657554  Sep 14 23:19:14 2012 4.JPG
1347657554  Sep 14 23:19:14 2012 5.JPG
1347741772  Sep 15 22:42:52 2012 6.JPG
```

Make a new dir for them

```
$ mkdir renamed
```

Run through them with a loop

```
$ for i in *.JPG ; do cp -p $i renamed/`echo $i|sed 's/JPG$/jpg/g'` ; rm $i ; done
```

Now, they're in newdir and removed from current dir. But we want them back - can't use mv though.

```
$ for i in renamed/* ; do cp -p $i . ; rm $i ; done
$ rm -rf renamed/
```

Tadaa

```
$ stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" *
1347657595  Sep 14 23:19:55 2012 1.jpg
1347715529  Sep 15 15:25:29 2012 2.jpg
1156277764  Aug 22 22:16:04 2006 3.jpg
1347657554  Sep 14 23:19:14 2012 4.jpg
1347657554  Sep 14 23:19:14 2012 5.jpg
1347741772  Sep 15 22:42:52 2012 6.jpg
```

Comment: Okay, so, to be clear, when you used mv the dates WERE changed, right??

Comment: I never used mv, because as you correctly state, mv will change the attribute. When I said "make a new directory" i didn't mean to use mv, just cp, to get past the case sensitivity issue.

Comment: Good it's not just me. I don't get why the dates would change on a move. And I really don't get why they don't change when you rename in the finder but they do when you rename in the Terminal.  Thanks though! This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `touch -r` to set the timestamp of one file to another.

```
cp oldfile newfile
touch -r oldfile newfile
```

That `touch` says "Set the timestamp of `newfile` to the timestamp of `oldfile`."

Here's [a blog post with more about `touch` and how to use it](http://petdance.com/2011/07/the-touch-command-does-more-than-just-create-files/).

All of that copy + touch should not be necessary, though.  You say that the manual says that "mv says it does a copy and delete" but that's not accurate.  I'm thinking you may have misread it.  You should be able to use `mv` to rename a file.  You may be running into a problem because on HFS+, the Mac filesystem, filenames are case-insensitive, so "foo.jpg" is the same as "FOO.JPG".

Comment: +1 for touch. Just note that the copy in this instance must be to a different folder because the file system is case insensitive.

Comment: `cp -p oldfile newfile` does the same thing with just 1 command rather than 2. The problem is the whole case insensitivity thing.

Comment: Every time I copy a file the timestamps are changed. Is that a system setting then? I haven't changed many things from the defaults. If I rename from the finder, the timestamps are unchanged.